# Creating a totalizer in grafana from flow rate using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I have a table of data with timestamps and flow rate (in units of lbs/hour). I am trying to get the total amount of product over a certain time using Grafana and the singlestat panel.

Here is some example data:

```
dateandtime         val
5/7/2018 4:45:11    38.13187027
5/7/2018 4:45:21    38.14497757
5/7/2018 4:45:31    38.17045975
5/7/2018 4:45:41    38.20859528
5/7/2018 4:45:51    38.25962067
5/7/2018 4:46:01    38.29846954
5/7/2018 4:46:11    38.3375206
5/7/2018 4:46:21    38.35148621
5/7/2018 4:46:31    38.3652153
5/7/2018 4:46:41    38.39123535
5/7/2018 4:46:51    38.41730499
5/7/2018 4:47:01    38.4434433
5/7/2018 4:47:11    38.45699692
5/7/2018 4:47:21    38.47026825
5/7/2018 4:47:31    38.47062683
```

By hand I would do `(val/3600)*(to_epoch(nextTimestamp)-to_epoch(currentTimestamp))` for each record and then output the summation, but I am at a loss of how to do this in SQL.

Using that formula I would expect a value of about 0.86 lbs.